# How to optimize mysql Distinct?

Tags: mysql, sql

`Tbl_responses` has

- id
- response
- msgid
- username

There are 5,000 records.  800 responses were posted by "zac1987".  There are 30 difference `msgid` among the 800 responses that posted by "zac1987".

```
SELECT DISTINCT msgid 
  FROM Tbl_responses 
 WHERE username = 'zac1987';
```

Currently the Explain SQL shows that 800 rows are effected.  How to optimize the query so that only 30 rows will be effected? I think there must be a solution to avoid looping / filter through the 800 records... just like replacing WHERE clause with JOIN clause issue that show on my blog... [ye5.blogspot.com/2011/07/optimize-faster-mysql-query-speed.html](http://ye5.blogspot.com/2011/07/optimize-faster-mysql-query-speed.html) I am looking for some expert to come out a solution to avoid looping the 800 records.

My other question - Why this page http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Top10SQLPerformanceTips saying "Don't use DISTINCT when you have or could use GROUP BY" because it will slow down the query? But I have tested, the result didn't slow down, why?

Comment: i dont understand, you mean distinct and groupby use the same time?

Comment: I also don't understand the sentence on the page, i guess it mean use both distinct and groupby at the same time...

Comment: why dont you use one at a time and see wich one is faster

Comment: How do you expect to arrive at the 30 without examining the 800? What does Group By have to do with your question? There's no Group By in your query.

Comment: @lbu, I have tested, both are at the same speed with the same numbers of rows are affacted. @AndrewBarber, it is just the same as how I arrive 800 records without examining 5000 records. I need to use Group By too for my other query that didn't stated here.

Comment: Maybe the optimizer removes GROUP BY from the plan since you use DISTINCT and you have no aggregates, that's propably why performance didn't got worse

Comment: @niktrs, do you mind to show me the example of aggregates ?

Comment: The USE of GROUP BY and DISTINCT in your case is identical, so the optimizers plan remain's the same. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/29/sql-server-difference-between-distinct-and-group-by-distinct-vs-group-by/ the link is for SQL server but is recommended to read it

Comment: I don't really understand it... COUNT(*) is an aggregate function? So if I want to use COUNT(*), I cannot use Distinct and Group By at the same time because it will lost the optimization?

Comment: For small tables like this (current value of small being < 10000 rows) just let the database do its thing. You can optimize but no-one using the system would notice the difference so whats the point?

Comment: @James Anderson, maybe I can just treat it as a study/ knowledge? For your info, I play plurk.com for a year only but I have responded 38294 times. Just a year already > 38,000 records.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, try rewriting the query to use the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT msgid 
  FROM Tbl_responses 
 WHERE username = 'zac1987' GROUP BY msgid;
```

And see the difference in performance

Comment: Already tried, GROUP BY affected 800 rows, Distinct are affected 800 rows too. Use combination of GB and Dist together also affected 800 rows.

Comment: Do you really have performance problems here? in how much time does this query execute? (don't try to optimize what is working good)

Comment: 800 is not a problem yet, but when it come to 10,000, definitely it will slow down the query a lot.

Comment: It should not slow down - if you have an index on `username` and a decent MySQL cache - this query should not make troubles until hundreds of thousands of records for the same user

Comment: Are you sure about that? Because from what I understand the purpose of set index is to reduced the number of effected rows. It is to avoid looping through all the records to find a particular record for u. I have set index to avoid looping 5000 records to find the 800 records, but now I still need another way to avoid looping through 800 records to find the 30 records. How to avoid looping through the 800 records? If I don't avoid it, sure it will slow down the query speed because it need to waste time to scan through 800 records.

Comment: Yes, I am sure about that - it's ok as it is now - just make sure you have the index on `username` - and you're cool

Comment: Okay, thanks, I hope u are right, anyway I still doubting because it makes no sense... if don't need to avoid looping future of 10,000 records, why need to use index to avoid looping 5000 records at first place....

Comment: :) You don't *need* an index for 5000 records, anyway - it works much better - there is no magical point of when you need an index and when you don't. However, if you can optimize the query in simple ways like adding an index do it. When you have to optimize it by partitioning or, replication, or other rather advanced techniques, then wait until that is a must

Comment: I suggest you make a test table with 10K (or even 100k) rows and try the speed and execution plans, first with index on `username` and then with a compound index on `(username, msgid)`

Comment: I though there is a solution to avoid looping the 800 records... just like replacing WHERE clause with JOIN clause issue that show on my blog... http://ye5.blogspot.com/2011/07/optimize-faster-mysql-query-speed.html I am looking for some expert to come out a solution to avoid looping the 800 records...

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is called *premature optimisation* - basically  you are wasting resources (your time and company's money) on issues that are not critical :)

Answer (score 1):

Check if a covering index will perform better in your case.
http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/tag/covering-index/

Answer (score 1):

The two queries are equivalent:

```
SELECT DISTINCT msgid 
FROM Tbl_responses 
WHERE username = 'zac1987' ;
```

and

```
SELECT msgid 
FROM Tbl_responses 
WHERE username = 'zac1987'
GROUP BY msgid ;
```

I suggest you make a compound index on `(username, msgid)`. This will help either version of the query.

But it would be best if you made a test table with 10K (or even 100k, or 1M) rows and tried the speed and execution plans, first with simple index on `(username)` and then with a compound index on `(username, msgid)`.

The difference will be shown in the `Extra` column in the execution plan, where for the first case with the simple index it will show ***"Using where, using temporary"***, where in the second case, with the compound index it will show ***"Using where, using index"***

As Tudor pointed, worrying for speed with 5000 records is premature optimization. When you have 500K records or you see a drop in performance, you should start worrying.

---

Note: These two queries are **NOT** equivalent, so you can't always remove the DINSTINT clause by moving a field to the GROUP BY and expect same results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT msgid, response
FROM Tbl_responses 
WHERE username = 'zac1987' ;
```

and

```
SELECT msgid, response
FROM Tbl_responses 
WHERE username = 'zac1987'
GROUP BY msgid ;
```

Comment: actually i test it by seeing the effected rows without seeing the speed, because the more rows affected is mean the more times need to filter through the rows mean speed will be slower. Now I have see the output 800 rows are affected.

Comment: There is a difference in execution plan (see the "Extra" column). If you test with a 100K+ rows, you'll see the difference in speed too.

Answer (score 0):

Put some Condition Like WHERE username='zac1987' AND id='XYZ'
because it is not possible to filter row using distinct and group by only as per your requirment.

Comment: id is response_id, why do i need to specify response_id in WHERE clause? I give u example, let's say there are 10 posts, and I have sent a response onto 7 of posts. When other user send response to the posts, the system must check and tell me if any 7 of posts receive a new response. The system will not check the other 3 posts, it will check the 7 posts that I have responded only. That's why I need to select distinct msgid WHERE username="zac1987" and that's why I can't put id="XYZ" in WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm searching rows with an auto-increment, primary key `id` but with data that's duplicated in other columns. For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id`    INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `make`  VARCHAR(10),
    `model` VARCHAR(10),
    `color` VARCHAR(10)
);
```

| id | make | model | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ford | Explorer | Black |
| 2 | Ford | Explorer | Black |
| 3 | Dodge | Ram | Red |
| 4 | Hyundai | Sonata | Silver |

In my example above, I want to return all results except the second black Ford Explorer with the `id` of `2`.

But in practice, there are over one million rows in a table with a similar structure to this one and I'm finding that `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` queries aren't fast enough. The current indexes I have on the table don't seem to help either.

The way I solved this is by creating a `duplicate` column and having MySQL find all of the duplicates in advance. The row is marked as a duplicate if a previous row contains the same values in `make`, `model`, and `color`.

```sql
ALTER TABLE `test` ADD `duplicate` BOOLEAN DEFAULT NULL;

UPDATE `test` `t1`
JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(`id`) AS `first_id`, `make`, `model`, `color`
    FROM `test`
    GROUP BY `make`, `model`, `color`
) `t2` ON 
    `t1`.`make` = `t2`.`make` AND
    `t1`.`model` = `t2`.`model` AND
    `t1`.`color` = `t2`.`color`
SET `t1`.`duplicate` = (`t1`.`id` > `t2`.`first_id`);

CREATE INDEX `duplicate_index` ON `test` (`duplicate`);
```

So now I can simply run this query to return all the original, non-duplicate rows:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `duplicate` = FALSE;
```